# Creating a beta distribution Q-Q plot

Tags: r

My task is to create 100 random generated numbers from beta distribution and compare that random variable with beta distribution using quantile plot.
This is my attempt:

```
library(MASS)
library(qualityTools)
Random_Numbers_Beta <- rbeta(100, 1, 1)
qqPlot(Random_Numbers_Beta, "beta", list(shape = 1, rate = 1))
```

Unfortunately something is wrong. This is an error which occurs:

```
Error in (function (x, densfun, start, ...)  : 
'start' must be a named list
```

Can something be done with that issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you had to specify that `list(shape = 1, rate = 1)` is the `start` parameter; right now this list is being treated as a value for the `confbounds` parameter. Second, it's actually not `shape` and `rate`, but `shape1` and `shape2`, as in, e.g., `?dbeta`.

```
qqPlot(Random_Numbers_Beta, "beta", start = list(shape1 = 1, shape2 = 1))
```

[image]

Again inspecting `?qqPlot` you may see that `...` is for "*further graphical parameters: (see par).*" Hence, you may modify the plot the way you like; e.g., adding `col = 'red'`.

Also notice that Beta(1,1) is simply the uniform distribution on [0,1] and, hence, its quantile function is the identity function. That is, `qbeta(x, 1, 1) == x` for any `x` in [0,1]. So, you may also simply work directly with

```
x <- seq(0, 1, length = 500)
plot(quantile(Random_Numbers_Beta, x), x)
abline(a = 0, b = 1, col = 'red')
```

[image]

if you don't need the confidence bounds.

---

One can notice, however, that the two plots are a little different. Given your task, it would seem that you need the second one.

In the first one, it looks like `qqPlot` fits a beta distribution for your data and uses its quantiles, which apparently isn't exactly the identity function. That is, it doesn't use the exact knowledge about the parameters. The second plot uses this knowledge.

Comment: Thank you! Your post is very helpful. Is it possible to change the look of the dots?

Comment: @Hendrra, also I added a comment about the choice of `qqPlot`, it may be not the right approach (given how you formulated your task).

Comment: Your comment is really useful. Thank you! It's true that I haven't noticed it.

Comment: In a similar task for normal and exponential distribution can I use identity function too?

Comment: @Hendrra, no, only the uniform on [0,1] has this quantile function. Instead of plotting `x` on the y axis you can then plot `qnorm(x)` and `qexp(x)`, along with specifying any needed parameters.

Comment: So I would have two plots and the second one would be just: plot(qnorm(x))?

Comment: One `plot(quantile(randomData, x), qnorm(x))` and another `plot(quantile(randomData, x), qexp(x))`.

Comment: You need `qexp(x, 2)` instead. And please rollback your edit, it's not how it works. If you wish to get more details, you should ask a new question.